# Return null from a stateless component/"functional component"

Tags: reactjs

I have a stateless functional component in React 0.14 that worked in React 0.13, but now returns the following error:

> No `render` method found on the returned component instance: you may
>   have forgotten to define `render`, returned null/false from a
>   stateless component, or tried to render an element whose type is a
>   function that isn't a React component.

This is my component:

```
function ToggleDisplay(props) {
    //should render a <noscript> per React's implementation
    if(props.if === false) {
        // return <noscript></noscript>; //do I have to do this manually now?
        return null;
    }

    let style = {};
    if(shouldHide(props)) {
        style.display = 'none';
    }
    return (
        <span style={style} {...props} />
    );
}
```

Do I have to manually return a `<noscript>` now? Is there another way to return null in stateless component?

Comment: why don't you just not render at the parent level?

Comment: There's also https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-component-empty

Comment: @DominicTobias This should be an accepted answer, I think. Prevent the component from being rendered in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Looks like not, this is a technical constraint in Javascript. To support arrow functions and plain functions as "components" React needs to know if we can call new on them.

> We can call new on everything if they're plain functions as long as
>   they return a ReactElement. However, that won't work for
>   null/false/string return values and we want to support those too. We
>   also can't call new on arrow functions. Likewise, we can't NOT call
>   new on classes.

[Relevant GitHub Issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4599)

Answer (score 21):

As of React 15.0, you can return `null` from a stateless functional component. (See [#5355](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5355)). No more having to return `<noscript />`

---

The change that made this possible is that React removed support for component classes that don’t inherit from `React.Component`, meaning they can reliably differentiate between React components (classes that inherit `React.Component`) and functional stateless components. So the PR to enable the functionality just involved removing and simplifying [the code](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/5884/files#diff-c807d0f5ebbc12c44d9479dea693bef6R159) that instantiates the components.

Comment: Error msg was really misguiding, solved for me... Had two versions of React in use